# How do you change the font for edge labels in a tikz graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

In the following example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\tikz {
    \graph [grow right sep=7mm] {
        a <-["label-1",bend left] b ->["label-2",bend left] c
    };
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would like to be able to change the font size for "label-1", "label-2". Adding `,every edge/.style={font=\sffamily\tiny}` to the `\graph` options does not do anything. Using `["{\tiny label-1}",bend left]` causes an error.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: As an addition to Zarko's answer, if you want to change individual labels, use e.g. `\graph [grow right sep=7mm] { a <-["label-1" {font=\tiny\sffamily, text=blue},bend left] b ->["label-2",bend left] c   };`

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image]

I add color to text only for reason of better visibility of the changes in labels' style. MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,                            % <-- added
every edge quotes/.style = {inner sep=2pt,                % <-- added
                            font=\tiny\sffamily, text=blue}
                        ]
    \graph [grow right sep=7mm] {
        a <-["label-1",bend left] b ->["label-2",bend left] c
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```